Wordpress website favicon issue in Google Serp
Good morning, our client's wordpress website (https://gruppobios.it) is experiencing an unusual issue.
The favicon doesn't appear in SERP, instead the GitHub favicon shows up.
We've followed all of Google's guidelines, conducted several checks on https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=https&site=gruppobios.it, and everything seems to be in order.
We've checked the URL in Search Console numerous times and processed the sitemap just as many times. The error has been ongoing for months and there doesn't seem to be a solution.
This is my code in header.php
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-48x48.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

How can we resolve the situation?
I've checked the favicon URL several times on Search Console, uploaded the sitemap on the same platform.
Created an icon package for the favicon through favicon generator (https://realfavicongenerator.net/) and followed all of Google's guidelines on the matter.
